# Google Auth sign in profile given name and family name empty when authenticating for the first time

Tags: android, authentication, googlesigninaccount

Am using Google Auth sign in and fetching profile details.

But am facing one issue. If the user authenticating first time the sdk will help to add the new account and once success it will get the call back on `onActivityResult` as

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
```

The `acct.getGivenName()` and `acct.getFamilyName()` are `null`.

But if I authenticating with an already added account both `acct.getGivenName()` and `acct.getFamilyName()` have the expected value.

My code as following

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestId()
                .requestProfile()
                .build();

GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .enableAutoManage(mActivity, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with the same question for a few hours without finding any responses on the internet. 
After a lot of blind guesses with no results, I've stumbled upon one that seems to do the trick:

I've created a "Web application" OAuth 2.0 client ID in my Developers Console and passed it when initializing the GoogleSignInOptions item like below:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(%Your Web application ID here%)
            .requestServerAuthCode(%Your Web application ID here%)
            .requestId()
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build();
```

Since then, it seems to be working just fine.